# CSS: clear on inline elements

Tags: css, css-float

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdqw1dsv/3/):

```
<IMG src="https://www.google.com.hk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="This image will illustrate floats">
<span>The contents of floats are </span>
```

The image is floated, and the `span` has `clear:both`. However, if the `span` has display value `inline` or `inline-block`, the clearance is not created. Only if it is `block`, the clearance is created.

I checked the [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#propdef-clear), it says:

> both: Requires that the top border edge of the box be below the bottom
>   outer edge of any right-floating and left-floating boxes that resulted
>   from elements earlier in the source document.

It doesn't mention how the `display` affects the creation of the clearance. Could anybody help to explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple: [`clear`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-clear) only applies to block-level elements.

> **'clear'**
>
> *Applies to*:    block-level elements

[Block-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-level) are defined as

> *Block-level elements* are those elements of the source document that
>   are formatted visually as blocks (e.g., paragraphs). The following
>   values of the [`display`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) property make an element block-level: `block`,
>   `list-item`, and `table`.